# How to get the json elements(key , value) in an object to be separated distinctly

Tags: json, key, jq

I am facing an issue with the simple Json mentioned below where I am trying to separately extract "hello" and "world" from this and store them separately. This JSON is coming out after extraction of original data and finally in this format.

```
{
  "key": "hello",
  "value": "world"
}
```

I am using jq already so `jq -r .key` i am aware of already (same for value). But I don't want this to be separate step. What I want is something like this.
Make a single call to the system that gives above json and store these "key" and "value" values in variables.

I very much appreciate help.

Comment: I don't think I follow what you're asking. Are you trying to get each value (`"hello"` and `"world"`) saved as a shell variable or a variable within jq? If the latter, `. as {$key,$value}`. Otherwise, any solution would be dependent on what shell you're using.

Comment: yep the first one, I want "hello" and "world" to be stored in some variable , can be any shell , I am primarily using bash. I want these values to be used later in my script hence the need is to store in some simple bash script variable. Like example `NAME=hello` and `SURNAME=world`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jq 1.7 introduced the `--raw-output0` flag which "will print NUL instead of newline after each output". You can use this in combination with `read` and its `-d` flag with an empty string as argument which "will terminate a line when it reads a NUL character".

```bash
$ { read -r -d '' key; read -r -d '' value; } < <(jq --raw-output0 '.key, .value' file.json)
$ echo "$key"
hello
$ echo "$value"
world
```

With older versions of jq (1.5+), use the `-j` flag to omit the newlines, and print the NUL character manually using `"\u0000"`:

```bash
{ read -r -d '' key; read -r -d '' value; } < <(jq -j '.key, .value | ., "\u0000"' file.json)
$ echo "$key"
hello
$ echo "$value"
world
```

Comment: This would work perfect @pmf. One last thing that file.json in my case is a little different scenario like. `{"key": "hello", "value": "world"} {"key1": "new", "value": "portal"}` , I am trying to separate them into separate small json but ...any thought would be great. But yes json cut in different altogether.

Comment: @vgdub What do you mean by "to separate them into separate small json"? You can use the same technique (`--raw-output0` or `-j` + `| ., "\u0000"`) with JSON objects. The shell variables would then be strings containing JSON-encoded objects instead of raw values. Maybe post another question where you can explicate the matter.

Comment: Oh nice, I haven't been tracking releases, but good to see a new jq version. `pick/1` looks really nifty. Could be useful for a lot of the questions that are typically asked here.

Comment: @Jeff The new `--raw-output0` flag, or new functions like `pick/1`, `debug/1` or `scan/2` (which was already documented but never implemented!), or the `if … then … end` shortcut, definitely do come in handy at times, but at the same time they were all comparably easy to post-implement (or work around) if missing (like in this case, or as seen in the [builtin.jq](https://github.com/jqlang/jq/blob/master/src/builtin.jq)). The real benefit comes from all the bugfixes for issues (like with `|= empty`, or with empty regex matches) which were often hard to track down when they happened to kick in.