# How to traverse through each JSON block and print out info

Tags: json, bash, shell, jq

I have a bash command that gives me the output in the form below, These are 1 block JSON objects , I get these after json > jq > output of this form from a file.

```
{
    "key": "hello",
    "value": "world"
}
{
    "key": "foo",
    "value": "bar"
}
{
    "key": "Disney",
    "value": "World"
}
{
    "key": "South",
    "value" "Africa"
}
```

Now my question is how can my bash script produce each JSON block separately. Like I want to iterate and lets say print each JSON block in this whole output I want to traverse each `{}` block and do something with it.

Please Note that command substitution is not helping in this case so storing the output in a file works but feeding this to command substitution fails as these curly braces also gets injected as a single line and not as a block ? Is there a way in bash to read and pass this as a block `{}` ?

Appreciate help!

Comment: Use `jq -c` to get an object per line

Answer (score 0):

Use the same technique as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77247944): jq 1.7 provides the `--raw-output0` flag which you can combine with `read -d ''`:

```bash
while read -r -d '' json
do printf "Using %s to do something.\n\n" "$json"
done < <(jq --raw-output0 . file.json)
```

```json
Using {
  "key": "hello",
  "value": "world"
} to do something.

Using {
  "key": "foo",
  "value": "bar"
} to do something.

Using {
  "key": "Disney",
  "value": "World"
} to do something.

Using {
  "key": "South",
  "value": "Africa"
} to do something.
```

With older versions of jq (1.5+), you can instead use the `-j` flag, and manually produce the NUL characters by changing the filter to `., "\u0000"`.

Comment: Thanks much @ pmf . Appreciate your help , I edited the question to find more info. The only issue left is bash command substitution picks each line and not block of JSON so if I don't store the output in file it breaks , any thoughts ?

Comment: @vgdub I can't follow. Did you use double quotes with bash variables? You always should (regardless of this). Take a look at my post: The `$json` variable is surrounded by double quotes, and the "Using … to do something." text is output exactly 4 times, once per object, embedding their full multi-line representation. If I had just written `printf "Using %s to do something.\n\n" $json` (note the missing quotes), 24 lines of output would have started with `Using`, one per line of representation: `Using { to do something.`, `Using "key": to do something.`, `Using "hello", to do something.` etc.

Comment: all is good and your solution works , the only issue that I am facing is that the first line and last line gives me this `jq: error Could not open file {` . This happens when i use it with command substitution for ex at the end we have `file.json` , in my case I am trying to directly pass that command which generate this output so like this.  ```while read -r -d '' json
do printf "Using %s to do something.\n\n" "$json"
done < <(jq --raw-output0 . "$(command)")```

Comment: But interestingly when I pass the whole file it works perfectly, I am only trying to avoid this separate file maintainence hence wanted to see if I can directly pass the command itself that generate that output.

Comment: @vgdub How do you generate multiple filenames using one `"$(command)"`? With quotes around it, you can only get exactly one filename. Without them, you *could* get more than one, but then they will undergo whitespace expansion, which is probably not what you want. Rather use appropriate tools like `find … -exec …` (esp. if your "command" started with `ls`), or at least some form of `… | xargs …`, both with the `jq` part as their arguments, not wrapped the other way round.

Comment: sorry let me give a context , I have a command that spits out the content I mentioned in the question above, this is key, value pairs without `comma` so single object key value json snippets. My command is a proprietary in house tool so can't use any other standard commands. Not sure if `xargs` can make it exactly like a json. Can you elaborate last sentence `both with the jq part as their arguments, not wrapped the other way round`